# Keeping iteration results as an array

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

How can I keep the results of all the iterations for all the quantities I want to compute as an array (row vector) at the end. this is my code.

```
#import numpy library
import numpy as np

#define the function to compute SHM main quantities for sevral masses
def SHM(k,x,m,v):
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        Fx = -k*x 
        ax = -(k/m[i])*x 
        w  = np.sqrt(k/m[i]) 
        f  = w/2*(np.pi) 
        T  = 1/f 
        Ek = (1/2)*m[i]*v**2 
        Ep = (1/2)*k*x**2 
        Et = Ek + Ep 
    
    return Fx, ax, w, f, T, Ek, Ep, Et

#Define the values you want to use for calculation
m = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
k = 200
x = 0.015
v = 0.40

#Call the function
out = SHM(k,x,m,v)

#disaply the results
display(out)
```

Any help would be appreicted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it is easy to use python List as below.

```
#import numpy library
import numpy as np

#define the function to compute SHM main quantities for sevral masses
def SHM(k,x,m,v):
    Fx = list()
    ax = list()
    w = list()
    f = list()
    T = list()
    Ek = list()
    Ep = list()
    Et = list()
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        Fx.append(-k*x)
        ax.append(-(k/m[i])*x )
        w1  = np.sqrt(k/m[i]) 
        w.append(w1)
        f1  = w1/2*(np.pi)
        f.append(f1)
        T.append(1/f1) 
        Ek1 =(1/2)*m[i]*v**2
        Ek.append(Ek1)
        Ep1 = (1/2)*k*x**2 
        Ep.append(Ep1)
        Et.append(Ek1 + Ep1)
    
    return Fx, ax, w, f, T, Ek, Ep, Et

#Define the values you want to use for calculation
m = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
k = 200
x = 0.015
v = 0.40

#Call the function
out = SHM(k,x,m,v)

#disaply the results
print(out)
```

output:

```
([-3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0], [-15.0, -10.0, -7.5, -6.0], [31.622776601683793, 25.819888974716115, 22.360679774997898, 20.0], [49.6729413289805, 40.55778675973612, 35.12407365520363, 31.41592653589793], [0.020131684841794818, 0.024656177762459992, 0.02847050173668708, 0.03183098861837907], [0.016000000000000004, 0.024000000000000004, 0.03200000000000001, 0.04000000000000001], [0.0225, 0.0225, 0.0225, 0.0225], [0.038500000000000006, 0.0465, 0.05450000000000001, 0.0625])
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @cnp's answer, you can also store values on every iteration so that you know the state of each variable upon each iteration of m.

```
#import numpy library
import numpy as np

#define the function to compute SHM main quantities for sevral masses
def SHM(k,x,m,v):
    iters = [] #create empty list
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        Fx = -k*x 
        ax = -(k/m[i])*x 
        w  = np.sqrt(k/m[i]) 
        f  = w/2*(np.pi) 
        T  = 1/f 
        Ek = (1/2)*m[i]*v**2 
        Ep = (1/2)*k*x**2 
        Et = Ek + Ep 
        iter = [Fx, ax, w, f, T, Ek, Ep, Et]
        iters.append(iter)
    
    return iters

#Define the values you want to use for calculation
m = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
k = 200
x = 0.015
v = 0.40

#Call the function
out = SHM(k,x,m,v)

#display the results
display(out)
```